# Vim run project specific make with key command?

Tags: vim, makefile

I'm working on a compiled project in Vim (Typescript). `make %` will build an individual file. I use this to check for errors. This is great for error checking, but it creates compiled files next to the source files that I don't need.

For my actual build process, I have a single command that compiles everything. This is in a Makefile.

I'd like to be able to map a key command to "build my whole project" in a generic way, so if I'm editing any `.ts` file underneath my project directory, it runs that specific command.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick would be to actually use a Makefile:

```
all: complete.exe

complete.exe: *.ts
     somecompilation-command $^ -o $@
```

This way, you can just leave `makeprg` at 'make':

```
:set makeprg&
```

And happily do:

```
:mak
```

Comment: Wow, that works really well. So the makeprg is pretty good as a default for the language. I don't want to change it globally for any `.ts` file. Is there a way I can change it for just `.ts` files in my project?

Comment: Combined with per-project .vimrc This makes everything better. http://damien.lespiau.name/blog/2009/03/18/per-project-vimrc/

Comment: As always, problems are combated with an extra layer of indirection :) To make this happen for all .ts files: see [`'modeline'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) and or something like `au! BufEnter *.ts se makeprg&`